# setting apex param- returning null in test class?

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage, apex-param

I have a visualforce page with a drag and drop calendar based on: https://salesforceprojects.quora.com/Implement-full-calendar-drag-and-drop-in-Visualforce-page

I have started to write my test classes.  The values of two strings are set on the visualforce page in apex: param Values.  When running my test these values are returning null.  I thought I could mimic this in my test class by using a getParamerters().put() in my test class, however when running my test these are still being passed into the method as null?

---

I am having trouble testing the setEvent method in the Extension:

```
public class CalendarControllerExtension {

    private final SalesActivityPlan__c sap; 
    public list <CalendarEvent> events {get;set;}    

    // As Events can be dynamically dragged around the calender variables are used for these selections
    public String eventIdTemp   {get;set;}  //Selected event Id coming from vf page
    public String st    {get;set;}  //Selected event start date & time
    public String ed    {get;set;} //Selected event end date & time
    public List <Event> eventList = new List <Event> ();

    //Do some stuff

//   Parse the date format and set values when an event is dragged around the calendar
    public void setEvent() {
        if (ed != null & st !=null){
        List <String> stringParts = ed.split('T');
        List <String> dateParts = stringParts[0].split('-');
        List <String> timeParts = stringParts[1].split(':');  
        DateTime dt1 = DateTime.newInstance(Integer.valueOf(dateParts[0]), Integer.valueOf(dateParts[1]), Integer.valueOf(dateParts[2]), Integer.valueOf(timeParts[0]), Integer.valueOf(timeParts[1]), Integer.valueOf(timeParts[2]));
        stringParts = st.split('T');
        dateParts = stringParts[0].split('-');
        timeParts = stringParts[1].split(':');
        DateTime dt2 =  DateTime.newInstance(Integer.valueOf(dateParts[0]), Integer.valueOf(dateParts[1]), Integer.valueOf(dateParts[2]), Integer.valueOf(timeParts[0]), Integer.valueOf(timeParts[1]), Integer.valueOf(timeParts[2]));
        for(Event e : eventList) {  
            if(e.Id == eventIdTemp) { 
                e.EndDateTime = dt1;
                e.StartDateTime = dt2;
                update e; }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Test Class:

```
@isTest

public class ActivityPlanExtensionTest {

@isTest    

static void TestActivityPlanExtension(){

    User u3 = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Email='test@test.com'];

    Event TestEvent = new Event(Subject = 'Test', ActivityDate=date.today(), StartDateTime=datetime.now(), EndDateTime=datetime.now());
    insert testevent;

    String ed = string.valueOfGmt(testevent.enddatetime);
    String st = string.valueOfGmt(testevent.startdatetime);
    String eventIdTemp = string.valueof(testevent.id);


    SalesActivityPlan__c testplan = new SalesActivityPlan__c();

    //Instantiate VF Page
    PageReference pg = Page.ActivityPlan;   
    Test.setCurrentPage(pg);
    ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('st', string.valueOfGmt(testevent.startdatetime));
    ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('ed', string.valueOfGmt(testevent.enddatetime));
    system.debug(st);
    system.debug(ed);

    // Instantiate the controller extensions and run the methods
    ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(testplan);   
    ActivityPlanExtension actplan = new ActivityPlanExtension(sc);
    CalendarControllerExtension calendarplan = new  CalendarControllerExtension(sc);
        calendarplan.pageLoad();
        st = ApexPages.CurrentPage().GetParameters().Get('st');
        ed = ApexPages.CurrentPage().GetParameters().Get('ed');
        calendarplan.setEvent();

}
}
```

Comment: These comments in your code are excessive and make it much harder to read.

Comment: Edited for clarity.

Comment: It still looks like the vast majority of this code is irrelevant to the issue. Can you try to reduce it to a Minimum Viable Reproduction case? MVR is much easier for the community to work with, and often the reductive approach will lead you to solving the problem yourself.

Comment: Can you try like this : `calendarplan.st = string.valueOfGmt(testevent.startdatetime);` ?

Comment: I've taken out a good portion of the code.  Hopefully it is more readable.

Comment: Did you mean to set `calendarplan.st` and `calnedarplan.ed` instead of `st` and `ed`? You'll have a much easier time working with this code if you work on sensible naming (for instance name your extension instance `extension` and your mental paradigm will be easier to grasp as you code).

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your controller where you are "getting" the page parameters so what's the point? Just set st and ed directly

Answer (score 0):

Credit to javanoob, Adrian Larson and Eric.

set calendarplan.st and calnedarplan.ed works perfectly.